Creating a light image generation model for a specific distribution
I am currently working on how a user can introduce bias in a neural network model.
To do so, I am creating an image2image model that only works on the training distribution.
For example, let's say I want my model to be good at replicating images of apples.
In that case, I will put only images of apple in my train set (input=apple image, output=apple image). After training, the model should be good only when given apple images as input, and garbage when given anything else (like car images).
I have a training database of roughly 100 pictures.
I want my model to light, so I avoided Transformers for now.
I also avoided using pre-tuned models like VGG, as these models are often too good in all cases.
For now, I tried training from scratch :

CNN / U-net style architecture

Auto Encoders

Variational Auto Encoders

Will try GAN soon, but I will be limited by my train set size.


Here are my results so far on a test set (which does not contain train set images):

Full blurry pictures with same output regardless of input (happens often when learning rate is too high).

Creating a blurry BUT different output depending on the input (underfitting I guess)

Only recreating images in the train set (overfitting, so I add more regularisation)

The output is more or less a copy of the input, regardless of what is the input (all inputs are correctly reconstructed, not only the training distribution).


As you can see, I am quite stuck right now. Either my models are garbage for everything or good enough for everything, and I can't seem to get exactly what I want.
Do you guys have any ideas or papers that tried a similar experiment?
Thanks a lot!
